# Exchange 2007 Content Filter is being to aggressive

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, spam-filter, whitelist

Some senders are getting the following return message:

`Error transferring to mail.server.com; SMTP Protocol Returned a Permanent Error 550 5.7.1 Message rejected as spam by Content Filtering.`

Content Filtering is currently set to Reject a SCL rating of 5 (tried dropping from a 6).

---

We have regular contact with several main companies. Is there a way to whitelist senders by domain? Is it efficient / effective? What kind of toll does it have on every message received?

I found and have tried using both of these in the exchange shell:

`Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenders foo@somedomain.com,foo2@somedomain.com
Set-ContentFilterConfig -BypassedSenderDomains example.com,foo.com`

However, while this works for companies that have their own domain, what should be done for those that have emails with global providers? (comcast, sbcglobal, gmail, hotmail, etc.)

What direction should I take? Do I have something set up incorrectly / strict?

Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have currently have setup the SCL level to 7 and have no spam so you can safely increase the value.

My advice is  to use IP Block List Provider (zen.spamhaus.org) which takes care for most of the spam. Also disable receiving emails to non-existing users and you should be fine.

You can [read here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996604%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) for more info on these settings.